# Excel VBA - use user input date (or use of a variable) in VBA formula R1C1

Tags: excel, vba, formula

I have to use and expand this formula in vba on certain cells but I have some problems when I try to not use some hardcoded dates in VBA.

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=COUNTIFS(JdT!R5C19:R490C19,"">=02/05/2016"",JdT!R5C19:R490C19,""<=24/05/2016"",JdT!R5C7:R490C7,RC7,JdT!R5C8:R490C8,R1C)+COUNTIFS(JdT!R5C19:R490C19,"">=02/05/2016"",JdT!R5C19:R490C19,""<=24/05/2016"",JdT!R5C7:R490C7,RC7,JdT!R5C10:R490C10,R1C)+COUNTIFS(JdT!R5C19:R490C19,"">=02/05/2016"",JdT!R5C19:R490C19,""<=24/05/2016"",JdT!R5C7:R490C7,RC7,JdT!R5C12:R490C12,R1C)"
```

I already have some variables:

```
start_date = DateSerial(start_year, start_month, start_day) // user input

end_date = DateSerial(end_year, end_month, end_day) // user input
```

Which I would like to use instead of the hardcoded dates in the formula. How can I do this?

Comment: `""">=" & start_date & """`   Does this work

Comment: Writing like this : "">=" & start_date2 & """ , seems to work. Thank you a lot Charlie